# Is it possible to create a map in runtime mode, which will be filled in passing through all documents and returned at the end ES

Tags: java, elasticsearch, opensearch

For ex: I have 2 documents with this body:

```
{
  "id": "doc_one",
  "name": "test_name",
  "date_creation": "some_date_cr_1",
  "date_updation": "some_date_up_1"
}
```

And the second doc:

```
{
  "id": "doc_two",
  "name": "test_name",
  "date_creation": "some_date_cr_2",
  "date_updation": "some_date_up_2"
}
```

What I want to do: to create two runtime field or Map('data_creation',count_of_doc_where_field_not_null_AND_the_condition_is_met).

For ex: I've got the 1st doc, there is date_creation IS NOT NULL and the condition startDate<=date_creation<=endDate is met, so, I create some field count = 0 and when I've got this case I do count++. When I will get all the docs I will set finally count value from map as result: Map('data_creation',final_count) and the same for another field but in the same map.

I tried to use script, but there is return Map for each doc, for ex:

```
{
            "_index": "my_index_001",
            "_type": "_doc",
            "_id": "1",
            "_score": 1.0,
            "fields": {
                "my_doubled_field": [
                    {
                        "NEW": 2
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "_index": "my_index_001",
            "_type": "_doc",
            "_id": "2",
            "_score": 1.0,
            "fields": {
                "my_doubled_field": [
                    {
                        "NEW": 2
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
```

Comment: did you tried aggregation ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have index below 3 documents to index where one document dont have `date_creation` field:

```json
POST sample/_doc
{
  "id": "doc_two",
  "name": "test_name",
  "date_updation": "some_date_up_2"
}

POST sample/_doc
{
  "id": "doc_one",
  "name": "test_name",
  "date_creation": "some_date_cr_1",
  "date_updation": "some_date_up_1"
}

POST sample/_doc
{
  "id": "doc_two",
  "name": "test_name",
  "date_creation": "some_date_cr_2",
  "date_updation": "some_date_up_2"
}
```

Now you can use `filter` aggregation from elasticsearch as shown below:

```json
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "date_creation": {
      "filter": {
        "range": {
          "date_creation": {
            "gte": "2020-01-09T10:20:10"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "date_updation": {
      "filter": {
        "range": {
          "date_updation": {
            "gte": "2020-01-09T10:20:10"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Response:**

```json
"hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 3,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : null,
    "hits" : [ ]
  },
  "aggregations" : {
    "date_updation" : {
      "meta" : { },
      "doc_count" : 3
    },
    "date_creation" : {
      "meta" : { },
      "doc_count" : 2
    }
  }
```

You can see `date_updation` field is available in 3 doc so it is showing count as `3` and `date_creation` field is available in 2 doc so it is showing count as `2`.

Comment: Thank you, Sagar! But is it possible to use with query? I mean I have to filter by startDate<=date_creation<=endDate OR startDate<=date_updation<=endDate

Comment: @Disteonne Please check my updated answer with `filter` aggregation.

Comment: and maybe I'm wrong, there is no OR operator...Let me to show you a case: if, for ex startDate<=date_creation<=endDate I have to increase a fictive count value from 0 to 1. with date_updation the same, but with another fictive value. And object can not have one of this field at all, or have all the fields but one of them or all of them may not fulfill the conditions

Comment: @Disteonne Please check my updated answer where condition is seprate for both the field and it will do count individualy.